# Function to copy rendered table randomly stops working, a page refresh fixes the issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I can't seem to figure out why this function stops working.  Refreshing the page fixes the issue.  What it does is take a table by ID, strip the classes and does some optimization on the styles.  The users are copying and pasting a generated table into their emails.

Can you spot why it's occasionally failing?  I don't see any errors in the console when it happens, and I can seem to figure out why it works fine most of the time.

A page refresh fixes the issue.

(this function is called onPress by a button in React.  It has worked for over a year just fine but has seemed to have stopped working in the last week sporadically and I can't find any package updates that may have effected it)

```
function copyByElementId(element: HTMLElement | null) {
    if (!element) return false;

    // Clone the node so we don't interrupt the view
    let el = element.cloneNode(true) as HTMLTableElement;
    el.className = ""; // Remove classes from parent Div

    if (comparedScenarios.length > 1) {
      // Delete last row if the arrows are present
      el.deleteRow(el.children[0].children.length - 1);
    }

    // Add default fonts to the table
    el.style.fontSize = "inherit";
    el.style.fontFamily = "San Francisco, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif";

    // This works for clients other than Outlook grrr...
    el.style.borderCollapse = "collapse";
    el.style.borderSpacing = "16px 4px";
    el.style.border = "0";

    let rows = el.children[0].children; // Rows in the table

    // Add padding to the left side of each cell other than the 1st column
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      let cells = rows[i].children;
      rows[i].className = ""; // Remove classes from rows
      for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i].className = ""; // Remove classes from cells
        // Only the 2nd column and after
        let cell = cells[i] as HTMLTableCellElement; // TD element
        cell.style.border = "0";
        if (i > 0) {
          cell.style.paddingTop = "0";
          cell.style.paddingRight = "0";
          cell.style.paddingBottom = "0";
          cell.style.paddingLeft = "20px";
        }
      }
    }

    // Create our hidden div element
    let hiddenDiv = document.createElement("div");
    hiddenDiv.style.position = "absolute";
    hiddenDiv.style.left = "-9999px";
    hiddenDiv.style.backgroundColor = "";

    // Render the table of the hidden div
    hiddenDiv.appendChild(el);

    // Check and see if the user had a text selection range
    let currentRange;
    let documentSelection = document.getSelection();
    if (documentSelection?.rangeCount && documentSelection?.rangeCount > 0) {
      // The user has a text selection range, store it
      currentRange = document.getSelection()?.getRangeAt(0);
      // Remove the current selection
      window.getSelection()?.removeAllRanges();
    }

    // Append the div to the body
    document.body.appendChild(hiddenDiv);
    // Create a selection range
    let CopyRange = document.createRange();
    // Set the copy range to be the hidden div
    CopyRange.selectNode(hiddenDiv);
    // Add the copy range
    window.getSelection()?.addRange(CopyRange);

    //since not all browsers support this, use a try block
    try {
      //copy the text
      document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch (err) {
      window.alert("Your browser doesn't support copy and paste! Error:" + err);
    }
    //remove the selection range (Chrome throws a warning if we don't.)
    window.getSelection()?.removeAllRanges();
    //remove the hidden div
    document.body.removeChild(hiddenDiv);

    //return the old selection range
    if (currentRange) {
      window.getSelection()?.addRange(currentRange);
    }
    runButtonStates();
  }
```

Comment: This is application in React.js?

Comment: Yes, React.  I should probably add a console.log or throw an error when the element isn't passed so that it doesn't silently fail.  Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: You shouldnt do that stuff in react. All that should be handled by react components. I think thats is your problem.

Comment: I don't follow - this is done in a component inside React.  A button (in React) calls the function which copies the table by ID.

Comment: It's not a good practice in React to manipulate DOM elements like this, instead you control the styles based on `props` and `state`.  Additionally a lot of the restyling can be handled by having or not having a single class name, rather than controlling multiple properties individually.

Comment: The table would have a variable `isSelected` that knows whether it is the selected table, and it render itself accordingly.  Each cell determines whether it is padded or not and returns something like `<td className={"table-cell" + isPadded ? " padded" : ""}>{content}</td>`.  You are never manipulating the `td` DOM element directly.  You control its class list based on the value of `isPadded` which is determined by `props` and `state`.

Comment: Your code (aside from whatever the bug is) is fine for vanilla JS, but it's not how you do things in React.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  This function *does* do what I want it to do most of the time.  As an alternative, how would you suggest I set up a button to copy a rendered table while stripping it of all classes?  (to prepare it to paste inside an email body)

Comment: actually, this should be fine in React, since you do a deep clone right out the gate. Only issue I could see would be if there was an id in your copied data. Where/how does this fail?

Comment: How do you handle `onPress` event? You might be hitting some issues with the `SyntheticEvent` https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling

Comment: I figured it out!  Turns out, it had nothing to do with the function itself.  That worked fine.  The issue was with, oddly enough, a separate transition component that was causing the rendered view to no longer be selectable.  I have no idea how or why it was occuring, but updating the Transition component fixed the issue.

Comment: What's the proper way to close a question that was answered by updating something completely different?  Should I just delete the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resulted from another React component that was blocking the viewport when it was first mounted (a modal overlay).  It didn't seem intuitive at first that this could be causing an issue with the native copy function in the browser.

After upgrading the component and reworking the overlay, it issue resolved itself.